# Java resize a shape with mouse

Tags: java, swing, resize, mouseevent, mouselistener

I can draw, select and move shapes like rectangle and ellipses.

I also want to let the user resize his shape.

My code for the `MouseEvents`:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
    start = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    end = start;
        if(buttonState == 5)
        {   
            for(int i = 0; i <shapes.size(); i++)
            {
                if(shapes.get(i).contains(start))
                {
                    shapeNumber = i;
                    if(shapes.get(i) instanceof Rectangle2D)
                    {   

                        handleRect = shapes.get(i).getBounds2D();
                        handleShape = handleRect;

                    }
                    else if(shapes.get(i) instanceof Ellipse2D)
                    {   
                        handleCircle = new Ellipse2D.Double(shapes.get(i).getBounds2D().getX(), shapes.get(i).getBounds2D().getY(), 
                        shapes.get(i).getBounds2D().getWidth(), shapes.get(i).getBounds2D().getHeight());
                        handleShape = handleCircle;

                    }

                    delta = new Point(e.getX() - (int)handleShape.getBounds2D().getX(), e.getY() - (int)handleShape.getBounds2D().getY());

                }
            }
             repaint();
        }
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {    
            Shape aShape = null;

            if (buttonState == 1)
            {
                aShape = drawCircle(start.x, start.y,e.getX(), e.getY());
            } 
            else 

            if (buttonState == 2)
            {
                aShape = drawRectangle(start.x, start.y,e.getX(), e.getY());
            }


            if(aShape !=null)
            {
              shapes.add(aShape);

            }

          start = null;
          end = null;
          handleShape = null;


          repaint();
     }
  } );

this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
{
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
  {
    end = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if(buttonState == 5)
    {
       int x = e.getX() - delta.x;
       int y = e.getY() - delta.y;

       if(handleShape instanceof Rectangle2D)
       {
          handleRect.setRect(x, y, handleShape.getBounds2D().getWidth(), handleShape.getBounds().getHeight());
          handleShape = handleRect;
       }
       else if(handleShape instanceof Ellipse2D)
       {    
           handleCircle.setFrame(x, y, handleShape.getBounds2D().getWidth(), handleShape.getBounds().getHeight());
           handleShape = handleCircle;
       }

    }
    repaint();
  }
});
```

I know that I have to add something to `MousePressed` and `MouseDragged`, something that takes the points of the selected shapes. So that I can drag it to make the shape smaller or bigger.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to code in this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Resizeashape.htm), there are 2 shortcomings which I have addressed in below code. There are further considerations that you have to adapt to your use:

- You work with multiple 2D shapes (you mention rectangle and ellipse). But the code here shows a single one of them. You need to work on it to support more than one at a time.
- Below solution works for shape movement in a single quadrant. So, needs additional work regarding bounds etc.
- This solution shows for ellipse. You can easily support rectangle by changing just one line (to):  `Rectangle2D s = new Rectangle2D.Double();`

Below is the working code with the enhancement and comments:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ResizeRectangle extends JPanel {
  private int SIZE = 8;
  //Below are 3 points, points[0] and [1] and top-left and bottom-right of the shape.
  // points[2] is the center of the shape
  private Rectangle2D[] points = { new Rectangle2D.Double(50, 50,SIZE, SIZE), 
                                   new Rectangle2D.Double(150, 100,SIZE, SIZE),
                                   new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 75,SIZE, SIZE)};
  Ellipse2D s = new Ellipse2D.Double();

  ShapeResizeHandler ada = new ShapeResizeHandler();

  public ResizeRectangle() {
    addMouseListener(ada);
    addMouseMotionListener(ada);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      g2.fill(points[i]);
    }
    s.setFrame(points[0].getCenterX(), points[0].getCenterY(),
        Math.abs(points[1].getCenterX()-points[0].getCenterX()),
        Math.abs(points[1].getCenterY()- points[0].getCenterY()));
    g2.draw(s);
  }

  class ShapeResizeHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    private Point2D[] lastPoints = new Point2D[3];
    private int pos = -1;
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
      Point p = event.getPoint();

      for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        if (points[i].contains(p)) {
          pos = i;
          // initialize preDrag points
          for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
              lastPoints[j] = new Point2D.Double(points[j].getX(), points[j].getY());
          }
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
      pos = -1;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
      if (pos == -1)
        return;
      if(pos != 2){ //if 2, it's a shape drag
          points[pos].setRect(event.getPoint().x,event.getPoint().y,points[pos].getWidth(),
              points[pos].getHeight());
          int otherEnd = (pos==1)?2:1; //Get the end other than what is being dragged (top-left or bottom-right)
          //Get the x,y of the centre of the line joining the 2 new diagonal vertices, which will be new points[2]
          double newPoint2X = points[otherEnd].getX() + (points[pos].getX() - points[otherEnd].getX())/2;
          double newPoint2Y = points[otherEnd].getY() + (points[pos].getY() - points[otherEnd].getY())/2;
          points[2].setRect(newPoint2X, newPoint2Y, points[2].getWidth(), points[2].getHeight());
      }
      else{ //Shape drag, 1,2,3 points/marker rects need to move equal amounts
          Double deltaX = event.getPoint().x - lastPoints[2].getX();
          Double deltaY = event.getPoint().y - lastPoints[2].getY();
          for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
              points[j].setRect((lastPoints[j].getX() + deltaX),(lastPoints[j].getY() + deltaY),points[j].getWidth(),
                  points[j].getHeight());

      }
      repaint();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Resize Shape2D");

    frame.add(new ResizeRectangle());
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the direction I want yes.  This is usefull for me, but I have still the problem that I want to let the user choose what they draw; Rectangle or Ellipse. So I put there choice in a Shape. But then I get errors at `handleShape.setFrame`, any ideas?

Comment: @Patrick, update your question on how far you were able to proceed and what is the current problem. Upvote my answer if it helps.

Comment: @Patrick One question per post, asked and answered. You need to open another question about how to change selections if you're still stuck. And don't forget to select this as the accepted answer if it solved the resizing problem.